# How do I call a function with a graphics object from another class?

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I want to call `paint()` from `main()` but I need a parameter.I don't know which parameter to pass and I can't seem to use the `Graphics` object when I define `g` outside the parameters since it can't be initialized.

I tried creating an object of the Graphics class in `main()` and then passing it as a parameter but then whenever I try to use g it gies me a nullException

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
 class Boards extends Canvas
{
    JFrame frame;    
     void frame()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SNAKES AND LADDERS");
        Canvas canvas= new Boards();
        canvas.setSize(1000,1000);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.getGraphics();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        Graphics g;

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
      g.fillRect(0,0,100,1000);
    }
}

 class snakes_and_ladders
{
    Scanner s= new Scanner (System.in);
    Boards board= new Boards();
     void main()    
    {
        board.frame();
        board.paint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to call [repaint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint(long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). From the docs:

`public void repaint(long tm,
            int x,
            int y,
            int width,
            int height)`

> Adds the specified region to the dirty region list if the component is
>   showing. The component will be repainted after all of the currently
>   pending events have been dispatched.

EDIT

An example of indirect parameterization:

```
protected String test = "foo";

public void myRepaint(long tm, int x, int y, int width, int height, test) {
    this.test = test;
    repaint(tm, x, y, width, height);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    //do something with this.test
}
```

Comment: I renamed paint() to repaint().Now I don't get a syntax error but it does not draw a rectangle onto the canvas.This is a snippet-                                               public void repaint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.fillRect(0,0,100,1000);
    }
}

 public class snakes_and_ladders
{
    Scanner s= new Scanner (System.in);
    Boards board= new Boards();
     void main()    
    {
        board.frame();
        board.repaint();

Comment: @Mendax don't rename your paint method, but call repaint in your snakes_and_ladders class.

Comment: It works now.Thanks a ton.But could you please tell me why it works?Why does paint() get called when I call repaint()?

Comment: @Mendax it's simple. Your Boards class extends Canvas, which, on its turn extends the Component class. The Component class has methods, like paint and repaint. repaint invalidates a region, generates a Graphics object and then calls paint(), passing that Graphics object. Since you have overriden paint, in your class that means that your paint method will be called by repaint. So, calling paint is more-or-less a private affair, even if it's marked public and it's better to delegate this call to repaint.

Comment: @Lajos_Arpad Thank you once again.Is it possible to pass values to paint() like can I add parameters to paint()?

Comment: @Mendax paint() should have a Graphics parameter, but you can define a method where you pass parameters and that would call repaint. If the parameters passed to the method are reused in paint, then it has a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

To redraw your graphic area, don't call the `paint` method directly but use the `invalidate` method instead.

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use `Swing` extend `JPanel` and override `paintComponent`.  `Canvas` is an `AWT` class and you should not mix `Swing` and `AWT` capabilities.

And make certain that you call super.paintComponent() as the first statement.  To repaint the panel all you need to do is call `repaint()`.

You should never call a paint method directly as it painting should be done in the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  Nor do you need to safe the graphics context.

Here is a very simple example that demonstrates movement.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MovementDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

   JFrame frame      = new JFrame("Movement Demo");
   int    size       = 500;
   int    x          = 50;
   int    y          = 200;
   int    diameter   = 50;
   int    yinc       = 2;
   int    xinc       = 2;
   int    xdirection = 1;
   int    ydirection = 1;

   public MovementDemo() {
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
      frame.add(this);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new MovementDemo().start());
   }

   public void start() {

      Timer timer = new Timer(100, this);
      timer.setDelay(5);
      timer.start();
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

      if (x < 0) {
         xdirection = 1;
      }
      else if (x > size - diameter) {
         xdirection = -1;
      }
      if (y < 0) {
         ydirection = 1;
      }
      else if (y > size - diameter) {
         ydirection = -1;
      }
      x = x + xdirection * xinc;
      y = y + ydirection * yinc;
      repaint();
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2d.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);

   }
}
```