# How do you paint a variable from outside paint()?

Tags: java

I want to be able to access an array from outside paint(). Is there a way to have the array declared in the main method and then have the value used in paint() and drawn out with the g.drawString()?

```
public class design
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    JFrame window = new JFrame ("Game Screen");
    window.getContentPane ().add (new drawing ());
    window.setSize (500, 500);
    window.setVisible (true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}

class drawing extends JComponent
{
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    int[] [] word = {{5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0},
            {8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3},
            {4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1},
            {7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6},
            {0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 7, 9}};
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle rect;
    for (int x = 0 ; x < 9 ; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0 ; y < 9 ; y++)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle (x * 50 + 5, y * 50 + 5, 50, 50);
            g2.draw (rect);
            if (word [y] [x] == 0)
            {
                g.drawString (" ", x * 50 + 30, y * 50 + 30);
            }
            else
                g.drawString (Integer.toString (word [y] [x]), x * 50 + 25, y * 50 + 35);
        }
    }
    g.fillRect (153, 5, 3, 450);
    g.fillRect (303, 5, 3, 450);
    g.fillRect (5, 153, 450, 3);
    g.fillRect (5, 303, 450, 3);
}
}
```

Comment: You must paint from `paint` but can access instance fields`  And you are painting incorrectly, please check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124471/how-do-i-call-a-function-with-a-graphics-object-from-another-class/57126330#57126330)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. An instance of a class can have variables that it can access within its own code, and you can ask for those variables while it was instantiated. So here, when you declare your drawing class, you can give it a variable for an int[][]. This would look like

```
class drawing extends JComponent {
    private int[][] word;
    public drawing(int[] [] word) { 
        //This replaces your normal contstructor. So instead of calling "new drawing()" you will call 
        //"new drawing(word)" where word is your instantiated array.
        this.word = word; //this assigns the word you were given to your class's variable
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) { ...
```

Here you continue, but you don't have to declare your array. You would have already declared your array in the second line of your main method, and then pass it into the drawing when you declare a new drawing.

Hope this helps!